# Data Load from DB2 to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, db2, azure-data-factory, db2-400

I'm performing data load from on-Prem DB2 system to Azure SQL DB using ADF V2 through Self-hosted IR. SHIR is having direct connectivity/access to both source and target system.

For some of the table its failing with below error:

```
 Error Message:

 Failure happened on source 
 side.'Type=Microsoft.HostIntegration.DrdaClientException, Messgae=Non- 
 negative number required.\r\nParameter name: count SQLSTATE=HY0000 
  SQLCODE=-343, Source=Microsoft.HostIntegration.Connectors
```

And this error is happening at different record count. For e.g in the first it will fail at 100th record then in subsequent run it will fail at different row count. Like shown below:

[image]

And since the error is happening at the source end i'm unable to capture the error log at destination. In my pipeline i have only copy activity, please help to find solution for this issue.

What are the things that i need to check/debug so that i can get the real cause for this issue.

Comment: You tagged db2-400, does this mean your Db2 server is running on i-series?  If not, give the Db2-server platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows), and also give the Db2 version.  The SQLCODE=-343 ( google SQL0343N) suggests there is an error in the SQL statement that Db2 receives, but that may not explain why it's happening at different row-counts. If you have a DBA for Db2, you can ask for a trace of the SQL. You could also open a support case with Micrsoft, in case its tooling allows tracing of the SQL sent to the source.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right you are using SHIR and it seems that the failures happens at different record number in subsequent runs ( even if nothing is fixed at the source ) .

I suggest you to look at the SHIR log and see if that has more info , the error "343" reminds me that I have seen this before on some other forum and I think the work around was to pull a small chunk of data , not sure if you can try that .

Comment: How do i fetch SHIR logs. Any specific steps to follow.

Comment: On windows start -> Search ->Intergration Runtime -> Diagnostics -> View logs

Comment: I checked with Microsoft ADF support team and they suggested to replace this Microsoft.HostIntegration.Connectors.dll in Integration run time box. This updated dll can be fetched by installing latest Power BI desktop tool.